# jce popup not working on ajax content . in joomla

Tags: javascript, ajax, joomla, popup

I'm working with joomla. 
I have used ajax to display some a section on a page. In that ajax loaded section, I kept a jce popup link like

```
<a href="some link" class="jcepopup noicon">
```

When I click on this link, JCE popup is not working.
Is there any script to add with in this case ?

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Understand how to write code. Indent with 4 spaces.

Comment: i have given the jce popup link on ajax loaded content. but popup is opened. When i give the same link on normal document, its working.

Comment: You need to add the JavaScript content too.

Comment: can i know that script.?

Comment: Right, you need to Delegate the events.

Comment: Im working with joomla. Here I have not used any script for popup, have installed jce media box plugin. And i tried even including jquery in the ajax loaded content. Still im not getting. But the same link is working on normally loaded contents.

Comment: @praveen Thank you for your valuable response. I got a script that suits my requirement,and have posted it as ans.

Comment: Muthu, I haven't helped you at all. I will vote your answer up for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that, we need to add the following script in ajax loaded content.

```
<script>window.jcepopup.create();</script>
```